# Adding a Google Calendar using apiClient

Tags: php, insert, google-calendar-api

I'm finally able to get an Access Token, now I'm very confused as how to add a Calendar using only Google's provided apiClient.

```
$apiClient = SiteController::getApiClient();

$service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

$calendar = new Calendar();
$calendar->description = "What";

$service->calendars->insert($calendar);
```

This produces:

```
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars?key=mykey: (400) Required
```

Is there some documentation/examples on adding a Calendar?  There are a ton of examples, it seems like, for simply adding an Event.

---

I'm a little closer now, I get

```
apiServiceException

Error calling POST 

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=mykey: (404) Not Found
```

Using the boilerplate code they gave on the documentation

```
$calendarListEntry = new CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("calendarId");

$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

---

[Inserting a new calendarEntry in google calendar API v3 returns a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052792/inserting-a-new-calendarentry-in-google-calendar-api-v3-returns-a-404)

How do I change my request URL from

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=mykey
```

to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars
```

---

This worked:
            // Create new calendar
            $apiClient = SiteController::getApiClient();

```
        $service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

        $calendar = new Calendar();
        $calendar->setSummary(Home::model()->count() . '-' . $model->name);

        $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me alot. What does this say about the doc. I did what you did and tried to use the boilerplate code they gave on the documentation and got the exact same error.  How did you find the way you are doing it here that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference [Google Calendar API v1 Developers' Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php).

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out  
[Google Api, CalendarList->Insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert)